# Chrome doesn't block requestus with devtools

Tags: google-chrome, devtools

I entered "s.amazon-adsystem.com" in Chrome's Network Request Blocking, but the requests go through anyway. There is really nothing more to add. Could some of you try adding that domain for yourself and seeing if Chrome will block it?
Edit: Blocking "*.amazon-adsystem.com" doesn't work either

Answer (score 0):

For me, I noticed that the setting "Enable network request blocking" under "Network request blocking" tab was off, and I had to turn it on so the requests will not be blocked.

[image]

Comment: It was on for me